# Encoding not working with searchTwitter in R

Tags: r, twitter

I'm having a problem with the encode of my search for some twetts. Below is my code (after authentication):

```
load("twitteR_credentials")
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")


mach_tweets = searchTwitter("bradesco", n=10, lang="pt", cainfo="cacert.pem", encoding='utf-8')

mach_text = sapply(mach_tweets, function(x) x$getText())
```

When I print the content of march_text, I get:

```
 [1] "Sexta meu amor, eu amo vocÃª! (@ Bradesco Promotora) http://t.co/evFs3BnvbV"                                                                       
 [2] "RT @LeiSecaFortal: â€œ@luciadeboraa: @LeiSecaFortal acidente entre tÃ³pic 06 e um palio na Av. AntÃ´nio sales em frente ao bradesco.transito leâ€¦"
 [3] "RT @LeiSecaFortal: â€œ@luciadeboraa: @LeiSecaFortal acidente entre tÃ³pic 06 e um palio na Av. AntÃ´nio sales em frente ao bradesco.transito leâ€¦"
 [4] "RT @DanielSoaresmh: I'm at Bradesco (Cajazeiras, PB) http://t.co/Zl3pgZ01ND"                                                                       
 [5] "RT @EquipeManuGTeen: Quem jÃ¡ comprou seu ingresso pro show da @manugavassi em SP, dia 6/4 no Teatro Bradesco?"                                    
 [6] "I'm at Bradesco (VitÃ³ria da Conquista, BA) http://t.co/wmWPnRsY7z"                                                                                
 [7] "RT @proconspoficial: Bradesco nÃ£o pode bloquear ou cancelar cartÃ£o de crÃ©dito de inadimplente com o banco http://t.co/zjf27oAKkK"               
 [8] "ALÃ” EMBU BUAÃ‡U! \nA Estrela lojas e o banco Bradesco agora uniram-se para facilitar sua vida. EXATAMENTE! Evite... http://t.co/nUvYQ3J2o3"       
 [9] "SERVIÃ‡OS: No @CidadeJardimRN temos caixas eletrÃ´nicos do Banco do Brasil, Banco 24h, Caixa EconÃ´mica, Bradesco, Santander, ITAÃš E HSBC."       
 [10] "RT @estelanaime: @Bradesco se encontrar um leitor de cÃ³digo de barras."
```

Does anyone know how to solve this encode problem?

Here's some info:

```
 sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] seqinr_3.0-7       wordcloud_2.4      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.11.0        tm_0.5-10          twitteR_1.1.7      rjson_0.2.13
 [8] ROAuth_0.9.3       digest_0.6.4       RCurl_1.95-4.1     bitops_1.0-6       sp_1.0-14          ggplot2_0.9.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 dichromat_2.0-0  grid_3.0.2       gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.2     lattice_0.20-23  MASS_7.3-29      munsell_0.4.2
 [9] parallel_3.0.2   plyr_1.8         proto_0.3-10     reshape2_1.2.2   scales_0.2.3     slam_0.1-31      stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.0.2

I'm using Windows 7 and Rstudio   Version 0.97.336

update: Using a linux machine it works fine.

```
sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C
 [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] twitteR_1.1.7      rjson_0.2.13       seqinr_3.0-7       tm_0.5-10          ggplot2_0.9.3.1    ROAuth_0.9.3       digest_0.6.3
 [8] RCurl_1.95-4.1     bitops_1.0-6       wordcloud_2.4      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.10.6        data.table_1.8.10  RJDBC_0.2-1
[15] rJava_0.9-4        DBI_0.2-7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-29      colorspace_1.2-4 dichromat_2.0-0  grid_3.0.2       gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.2     munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.0.2
 [9] plyr_1.8         proto_0.3-10     reshape2_1.2.2   scales_0.2.3     slam_0.1-31      stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Sys.setlocale`?